# Not enough research effort flag

Tags: discussion, flagging, insufficient-effort

Is there a flag for flagging as insufficient research effort? Or do I need to use a custom reason flag? (Should I even flag a question as such? I know a lot of people do...)

Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Same question came up in chat from me today; see also http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question

Comment: (1) Note that custom close reasons (you'll be able to access at 3k rep) are "better" than custom flags. The former put a question into the close queue for all 3k+ rep users, the latter can only be seen by mods and must be handled by them. (2) Yes, a lot of people speak about research effort, but I'm [not convinced](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8789/what-does-everyone-mean-by-insufficient-research-effort) this is anything other than trying to delete content they personally find uninteresting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, there is not a flag for insufficient research effort. And I would say you shouldn't flag for that. If you have the ability to vote to close with a custom reason, you can do that, and downvoting is also a good idea, but it's not the sort of thing we're really comfortable handling with unilateral moderator action.

We have been talking about replacing the homework policy with a new policy which will likely focus on insufficient effort. So when that process is complete, we probably *will* have a close reason (and a flag) for it.

Comment: Does insufficient research effort apply only to "homework-like" questions, or to all questions?

Comment: @sammygerbil It applies to all questions, you may have noticed what the tooltips say for up/down vote buttons, questions asking for answers that could be obtained simply by Googling are discouraged.

Comment: Good idea, many questions on the MathSE are homeworks, _but_ actually wants help and not on the "here is my scanned homework, solve me now" line.